# Javascript calculation with multiplying

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, calc

I have 3 text inputs as you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HrElmo/NKddu/)

The thing I need is a JavaScript calculator that will multiply the first input value by 0.04, the second input by 0.04 and the third input by 0.08 and then add all them together and echo it. And it should also echo quantity of three inputs.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="vaartus">
  <div>1<input type="checkbox" id="v1" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="v1_v" id="v1_v" disabled="disabled" /></div>
  <div>2<input type="checkbox" id="v2" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="v2_v" id= "v2_v" disabled="disabled" /></div>
  <div>3<input type="checkbox" id="v3" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="v3_v" id="v3_v" disabled="disabled" /></div>
  <div><input type="submit" name="arvuta" value="Arvuta" /></div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('v1').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('v1_v').disabled = this.unchecked;
};
document.getElementById('v2').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('v2_v').disabled = this.unchecked;
};
document.getElementById('v3').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('v3_v').disabled = this.unchecked;
};
```

Comment: See, `InputElement.value`, `parseFloat`, `*`, `+` and `alert`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div><input type="submit" name="arvuta" value="Arvuta" onclick="multi()" /></div>
```

put function on click and in that function get the values of input tags like this

```
function multi(){
var val1 = document.getElementById('v1_v').value;
var val2 = document.getElementById('v2_v').value;
var val3 = document.getElementById('v3_v').value;
alert((val1*.04) +(val2*.04) + (val3*.08));
```

}

and you can put checks and parse inputs into integer or what ever in this function.